# VirtualBox W7 - cannot bind localhost to host's localhost

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, localhost

I have an auth server which requires communication with `localhost`, so using `10.0.2.2` with NAT or my local IP address with Bridged Adapter won't do.

However putting:

```
10.0.2.2 localhost
```

Does nothing, localhost is unreachable (same when using the Bridge adapter and my IP which otherwise works). It only works if I give it any name other than localhost.

This is a clean Windows 7 image from MS with no modifications. How can I get localhost to load localhost on my host machine? Thanks.

Comment: Not a solution, but perhaps you can use port forwarding on the guest as a workaround.

Comment: Like @Nifle said, you can set port forwarding on the guest OS. Check this out https://superuser.com/a/1200719/502087